# Как в bash преобразовать миллисекунды в секунды с округлением до второго знака?

Tags: bash, sh

Есть число в миллисекундах. Например 564. Нужно получить кол-во секунд округленных до второго знака, то есть 0.56? Использовать баш или пакеты, которые стоят по умолчанию в centos/debian. bc например не годится. Арифметических действий потом с числом производится не будет, так что достаточно получить строку на выходе

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/110559

Comment: *Использовать баш или пакеты, которые стоят по умолчанию в centos/debian. bc например не годится.* — программу python используйте, например.

Comment: в любой posix-совместимой оболочке: `$ echo "0.${m%?}"` (убрать последний символ и дописать в начало `0.`

Comment: Вот так можно `awk '{printf "%.2f", $1 / 1000}' <<< 564`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда, которая подходит требованию:

```
awk '{printf "%.2f", $1 / 1000}' <<< 564
```

В данном случае мы используем интерпретатор awk, передаем в него значение миллисекунд.
В самой конструкции это значение будет подставляться вместо `$1`

Для перевода миллисекунд в секунды мы делим значение миллисекунд на 1000, часть после запятой `$1 / 1000`, при этом полученное значение на печать выводим при помощи `printf` с использование параметра `"%.2f"`, который выводит 2 цифры после запятой с округлением к ближайшему целому.

В данном примере если у нас значение миллисекунд будет более 1 секунды скажем **564564**, то данная команда вернет результат: **564.56**

Comment: Это не `bash`, а `awk`.

Comment: @0andriy, а вы наблюдательны, все верно, в `shell` скрипте вызывается интерпретатор `awk` и математические действия выполняются им, если у вас есть более простое и лучшее решение, то можете написать его. Так же закрадывается мнение, что у человека с микрофоном есть какая-то личная неприязнь ко мне))

Comment: Никакой неприязни, просто спрашивают про Фому, а отвечают про Ерёму.

Comment: @0andriy ТС пишет Цитата:"Использовать баш или пакеты, которые стоят по умолчанию", `awk` идет из коробки на большинстве дистрибутивов, в чем придирка то?

Answer (score 3):

С использованием bash'евских арифмитических операций `$(( ))`:

```
n=5645
echo $(( $n/1000 )).$(( ($n % 1000)/10 ))
```

Вывод:

```
5.64
```

Последовательность вычислений:

1. Выделяем полные секунды
2. Выделяем миллисекунды из неполной секунды и оставляем только 2 знака
3. Склеиваем в строку полученные результаты через знак `.`

**UPD:**
Если нужно избавится в полученном результате от одиночного нуля после запятой, то делается это так: `res=${res%.0}`

Comment: если *n* будет *4* цифры, которые целые, к примеру *5000*, то возвратом будет  *5.0*, так же во второй части лишняя скобка внутри выражения, ее можно убрать `$(( (($n % 1000))/10 ))` = `$((($n % 1000)/10 ))`

Comment: @PotroNik, за скобки спасибо, поправил

Comment: @PotroNik, дополнил про `.0`. спс